# Trying to tweet from Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, omniauth

In my rails app I'm letting a signed in user tweet from a certain part of the page. I've followed this tutorial but keep getting an error message when clicking on the submit tweet button.

Tutorial: http://richonrails.com/articles/sending-a-tweet-to-twitter

The error is: "Your credentials do not allow access to this resource"

Wondering if anyone else have experienced this.

Comment: What tutorial? What code? Nobody can begin to help you using only the information you've provided.

Comment: just realized my post got cut off short for some reason, i updated the tutorial and followed the steps

Comment: Did you check the read&write access part? Did you copy the right keys into the config/environments/development.rb?

Comment: Yes, Read and Write is selected. I also copied the right keys but included them in my application.yml file

Comment: But the tutorial insists you have the key and secret in config/environments/development.rb.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're receiving is likely the result of not authenticating your twitter credentials inside the API

---

**[sferik Twitter gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter)**

An alternative (which is why I've written an answer rather than comment) is to use the [sferik twitter gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) to post tweets. All you need to do is create an initializer to connect to the Twitter API:

```
#config/initializers/twitter.rb
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY"
  config.consumer_secret     = "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
  config.access_token        = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
  config.access_token_secret = "YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET"
end
```

Then you'll be able to send tweets using the `client` object:

```
client.update("I'm tweeting with @gem!")
```

Comment: Thanks Rich. Once I create the initializer where am I calling client.update?

Comment: You can call it where ever you need I think?